# Building RPM results in nothing generated in RPMS directory

Tags: linux, rhel, buildroot, rpmbuild

I am building a **RPM** on RHEL.

After following https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_create_an_RPM_package, I put my `front.tar.gz` in `/rpmbuild/SOURCES`, and make the `spec` file like this:

```
Name: front
Version:        1.1.0
Release:        1%{?dist}
Summary:        The web2py webserver

Group:          Applications/Internet
License:        GNU
URL:            https://xxx
Source0:        https://xxx
BuildRoot:      %(mktemp -ud %{_tmppath}/%{name}-%{version}-%{release}-XXXXXXX)

#BuildRequires:
Requires:       python2.6, python2.7, apache


%description

%prep
%autosetup -n %{name}


%build
%configure

%install
rm -rf %{buildroot}
install -d -m 755 %{buildroot}/var/www/
cp -r . &{buildroot}/var/www/front/


%clean
rm -rf %{buildroot}


%files
%defattr(-,root,root,-)
%doc


%changelog
```

Then, I do

```
rpmbuild -ba front.spec
```

in the `/SPECS`,

I can see many file are copied to the `/BUILDROOT/front.1.10-1.e17.x86_64/` but after that, the building process seems finished with no **RPM** file generated in the `/RPMS` directory.

There was no error or warning. Seems like the *bin* stage is never executed.

Does anyone know what could be the problem?

Comment: Can you post the whole output from `rpmbuild -ba`?

Comment: As an aside, you never declared any files in your `%files` section. Without any files declared, your package will be empty.

Comment: Also, why are you creating a package that requires a package called `python2.6` *and* a package called `python2.7`?  I doubt those packages are available on most RHEL systems (the Python package on all RHEL systems I know of is simply called `python`), and those packages look like they would conflict anyway.

Comment: hey Jay, thanks a lot for the hint! After putting /* in the %files section, everything works :D How silly this question was... anyway, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

It turned out to be a lack of /* in the %files section

```
%files 
%defattr(-,root,root,-)
/*
```

Comment: you can be tighter on this, you can do %{_prefix} instead of /*.  Then you'll be warned if there's any stray files that you weren't expecting.